# Initialize @Published var SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following

```
import Foundation


class TimeToEatTrackerViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var currentMeal: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CurrentMeal") {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.currentMeal, forKey: "CurrentMeal")
    }
}

@Published var startDay: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "startDay") {

    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.startDay, forKey: "startDay")
    }
}

}
```

I need to initialize `startDay` with `true`, how can I do that? I've tried several ways and it doesn't work, like putting this on top of didSet:

```
init(){
         startDay = false
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible variant

```
@Published var startDay: Bool

init() {
    startDay = true
    if let storedDay = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "startDay") {
        startDay = storedDay as! Bool
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you create a new variable name storedDay and what's its meaning?

Comment: @Arturo, by getting value from UserDefaults it is possible to know if it was stored before, so to override default only with really stored, but not cast nil to bool false.

Comment: Hi, how can I do the same implementation with dictionaries?

Comment: @Arturo, I was not in time to post my answer there :)... in that question condition all you need is to specify type of dictionary explicitly `@Published var mealAndStatus: [String: String]` and all works. Tested.

Answer (score -1):

not clear what you are asking here.
If you want to always initialise startDay to true when you run your app, then:

```
@Published var startDay: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.startDay, forKey: "startDay")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, the value would always be set to true. The objective of `UserDefaults` in this case is to store the previous value of startDay. You'r implementation always sets it to true. I need it a one time thing, for example when the app is installed for the first time